# Bootstrap Responsive 4 блока с права

Tags: css, bootstrap, responsive

Я верстаю сайт и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы вот эти блоки были адаптивными:

[image]

Но когда уменьшаю экран из-за того что контент ссужается оно чуть чуть вниз идет и образуются вот такие бреши:

[image]
  [image]

Не понимаю, почему так себя ведут стили

Пример [кода](https://jsfiddle.net/4a4p48qs/)

```css
.what-we-do-2 {
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../img/what-we-do.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  .col-lg {
    padding: 0;
  }
  // Inside Boxes
  .col-md-6 {
    min-height: 250px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: rgba(0, 55, 100, 0.6);
    // Making Lines - Little Transparent
    &: first-child {
      border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
    // Images of boxes in boxes
    .icon {
      width: 52px;
      height: 52px;
      background: no-repeat center center;
      background-size: 90%;
      position: relative;
      margin: 65px 0 0 65px;
      display: block;
    }
    // Different Box Images
    .icon-percent {
      background-image: url(../img/box-percent.svg);
    }
    .icon-wind {
      background-image: url(../img/box-wind.svg);
      background-size: 105%;
    }
    .icon-money {
      background-image: url(../img/box-money.svg);
    }
    .icon-simple {
      background-image: url(../img/box-simple.svg);
      background-size: 80%;
    }
    // Title 
    .what-title {
      color: #fff;
      margin: 5px 0 0 65px;
      font-size: 26px;
      font-family: 'MullerLight';
    }
    // Descr
    .descr {
      color: #fff;
      margin: 10px 0 0 65px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: 'MullerLight';
      line-height: 1.2em;
      br {
        line-height: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="what-we-do-2">

  <div class="container-fluid padding-0">

    <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right padding-0">

      <div class="col-md-6 padding-0">
        <!-- Box Icon -->
        <div class="icon icon-percent"></div>

        <!-- Heading Under Box -->
        <div class="what-title">Доставка без процентов.</div>

        <!-- Descr under title -->
        <div class="descr">Оплата фактического веса
          <br>по прибытию в Ташкент.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 padding-0">
        <!-- Box Icon -->
        <div class="icon icon-wind"></div>

        <!-- Heading Under Box -->
        <div class="what-title">Быстрая доставка.</div>

        <div class="descr">Доставка из Китая от 2 до 6 недель.
          <br>Без дополнительных ограничений.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 padding-0">
        <!-- Box Icon -->
        <div class="icon icon-money"></div>

        <!-- Heading Under Box -->
        <div class="what-title">Самая дешевая доставка</div>

        <div class="descr">Без комиссии, налогов штата
          <br>и транзакции.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 padding-0">
        <!-- Box Icon -->
        <div class="icon icon-simple"></div>

        <!-- Heading Under Box -->
        <div class="what-title">Собственный склад.</div>

        <div class="descr">Используйте наш склад в Европе
          <br>по тарифу 1 кг = 12$.</div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не вижу у вас в коде, ни одного класса `row`, каждый ряд с `col-*` должен быть обёрнут в `<div class="row"></div>`.

А вообще, такое надо сделать на флексах, с  `bootstrap` без фиксированной высоты у вас всё равно будет дырка если контент будет больше 250px по высоте. Пример нужно смотреть в режиме "на вcю страницу", потому что в редакторе сетка переходит в мобильный вид и становится на всю ширину:

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.block {
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: rgba(0, 55, 100, 0.6);
}
.block:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.block:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.block:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.what-title {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px 0 0 65px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: 'MullerLight';
}
.descr {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0 0 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'MullerLight';
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
br {
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
    <div class="flex-box">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="what-title">Собственный склад.</div>

        <div class="descr">Используйте наш склад в Европе
          <br>по тарифу 1 кг = 12$.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="what-title">Самая дешевая доставка</div>

        <div class="descr">Без комиссии, налогов штата
          <br>и транзакции.</div>
        <div class="what-title">Самая дешевая доставка</div>

        <div class="descr">Без комиссии, налогов штата
          <br>и транзакции.</div>
        <div class="what-title">Самая дешевая доставка</div>

        <div class="descr">Без комиссии, налогов штата
          <br>и транзакции.</div>
        <div class="what-title">Самая дешевая доставка</div>

        <div class="descr">Без комиссии, налогов штата
          <br>и транзакции.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="what-title">Самая дешевая доставка</div>

        <div class="descr">Без комиссии, налогов штата
          <br>и транзакции.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="what-title">Самая дешевая доставка</div>

        <div class="descr">Без комиссии, налогов штата
          <br>и транзакции.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам MasterAlex